# Ubuntu 18.04 problem mounting old ipod

Tags: ipod

I found my old ipod from years ago. Connecting it by USB cable results in this output from dmesg. Is there another way to mount it. The ipod model is A1099.

```
[   50.482808] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   50.610692] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   50.846689] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   51.082601] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   51.210607] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   51.446536] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   51.554553] usb usb3-port4: attempt power cycle
[   52.206269] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   52.334264] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   52.570170] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   52.806117] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   52.934035] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   53.170046] usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   53.278061] usb usb3-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: Related: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789